# Is it possible to add multiple images to Firebase Database with Firebase Storage? - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

In my Flutter app, I'd like the user to upload data and images to the Firebase database, which I have done successfully. The problem is that when I upload multiple images one URL from the Firebase Storage is provided to the database collection, but none of the other images. Is there a way to get all the image URL in one collection?

**My Flutter code for sending the data:**

```
var title = '';
var pageNo = 0;
var description = '';
var imgUrl;

Future sendData() async {
//Add the TextFormField data to the database
hwFormData
    .add({
      'title': title,
      'pageNo': pageNo,
      'description': description,
      'imgUrl': _uploadedFileUrl
    })
    .then((value) => print('Form data sent'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Failed to send data: $error'));
 _key.currentState!.reset();

//Send Images
firebase_storage.Reference ref;
for (var img in _image) {
  ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('hwImages/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
  await ref.putFile(img).whenComplete(() async {
    await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      hwFormData.add({'imgUrl': value});
      setState(() {
        _uploadedFileUrl = value;
        imgUrl = value;
      });
    });
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found. Had to change imgUrl to a List value then in the for loop have imgUrl add the value.

**New code:**

```
//TextFormField data
var title = '';
var pageNo = 0;
var description = '';
List<String> imgUrl = [];

Future sendData() async {
//Send Images
firebase_storage.Reference ref;
for (var img in _image) {
  ref = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('hwImages/${Path.basename(img.path)}');
  await ref.putFile(img).whenComplete(() async {
    await ref.getDownloadURL().then((value) {
      hwFormData.add({'imgUrl': value});
      imgUrl.add(value);
    });
  });
}

//Add the TextFormField data to the database
hwFormData
    .add({
      'title': title,
      'pageNo': pageNo,
      'description': description,
      'imgUrl': imgUrl
    })
    .then((value) => print('Form data sent'))
    .catchError((error) => print('Failed to send data: $error'));
//Resets the form data to null after it has been sent to the database
_key.currentState!.reset();
}
```